# how to fix error about proxybeanmethods()

Tags: java, spring-boot

I setup redisConfig.class. but when I see in my code that code need this dependency and this is the recommendation from the code:

```
<!--dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency-->
```

but when i add that dependency i got error like this :

```
 org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException: Attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication] is declared as an @AliasFor nonexistent attribute 'proxyBeanMethods' in annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration].; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration.proxyBeanMethods()
```

I have tried to delete my .m2/repository and download all dependencies again but still got the same problem. and I have a search solution in StackOverflow I cannot find the exact problem from this code.

that dependency use for this import import `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer;`
and work for this code :

```
@Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = this.getRedisConnectionFactory(
            this.redisHost, this.redisPort, this.redisDB, this.redisPassword);
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }
```

for springApplication i use this : `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.3.RELEASE`

and here my App.Java :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
/*@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients*/
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

if i don't add that dependency i got error like this :

```
[ERROR] C:\Users\test\service\src\main\java\id\config\RedisConfig.java:[9,51] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer
[ERROR]   location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache
[ERROR]  C:\Users\test\service\src\main\java\id\config\RedisConfig.java:[46,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer
[ERROR]   location: class RedisConfig
```

but when i change Dependency use 2.1.3.Release i got error like this :

```
 [ERROR] C:\Users\test\service\src\main\java\id\config\RedisConfig.java:[9,51] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer
    [ERROR]   location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache
    [ERROR]  C:\Users\test\service\src\main\java\id\config\RedisConfig.java:[46,4] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer
    [ERROR]   location: class RedisConfig
```

first i want to know how to use redis and how to configure the code in java
my question is how to fix this issue?

Comment: This looks like a version mismatch. If you're using Spring Boot 2.1.3 why are you using Autoconfigure in version 2.2.7?

Comment: because the recommendation of Autoconfiguration cache using 2.2.7. but i have change Autoconfigure use 2.1.3 still got same error

Comment: [ERROR] C:\Users\test\service\src\main\java\id\config\RedisConfig.java:[9,51] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer
[ERROR]   location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache
[ERROR]  C:\Users\test\service\src\main\java\id\config\RedisConfig.java:[46,4] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer
[ERROR]   location: class RedisConfig
when i use 2.1.3 for autoconfigure i got this error

Comment: Well, then you might have to upgrade Spring Boot to 2.2.7 as well.

Comment: or any idea for using autoconfigure 2.1.3 ? here ?

Comment: Well, if `RedisCacheManagerBuilderCustomizer` isn't present in 2.1.3 you might need to use an alternative. The code you've posted looks like you could do without that class but I can't tell for sure since I've only worked with newer Spring Boot versions so far.